# Searching column 1 for text contained in column 2 and highlighting red if NOT found

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, contains, conditional-formatting

I have the following example data set in excel.

[image]

Currently, for reference, **John,Smith is in A4 and Smith Johnson is in B4.**

Column 1 = Names of Members
Column 2 = Attended (list of members that attended a meeting).

Applied to column 1, I would like to add a function that turns GREEN any members that are in column 2 (attended) that are also in column 1.

Like so:

[image]

I am essentially trying to find a quick way of producing an attendance list, and highlighting those that were not present.

The difficulty is that it is not an exact match as the usernames in the attended list may contain the surname or last name but not in the format provided in column 1.

I should also mention that the attendees list could be variable, so the formula should ideally allow for a range from say B4 to B20, even if it is left blank.

Any clever and easy solutions?

Comment: Use wildcards with either COUNTIFS or MATCH.

Comment: BigBen, could you possibly post a solution please, so I can verify and accept. I tried a variation of field values and countifs but could not get it to work at all

Comment: Also, I tried using MATCH but for the reasons I've explained in my question, it doesn't work as column 2 fields are not an exact match. If the fields were the same it would be simple and I could just use conditional formatting, find duplicate values.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight those members that didn't attend:

[image]

- Select `A2:A9`
- Use conditional formatting formula rule:

  ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5&"*",$A2)))=0
  ```

I usually like to tell people that they will have to be carefull using partial matches to prevent false positives. What if you have someone called "Ann" and "Anne" and "Annet" and "Annette"? Therefor, allready a bit safer could be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",$A2)-1)=$B$2:$B$5))
```

---

EDIT:

Based on the new data and question you can try:

[image]

- Select `A4:A10`
- Use conditional formatting formula rule:

  ```
    =SUMPRODUCT(--(MID($A4&" "&$A4,FIND(",",$A4)+2,FIND(",",$A4&" "&$A4,FIND(",",$A4)+2)-FIND(",",$A4)-2)=$B$4:$B$6))
  ```

Comment: sorry where do I put in the formula?

Comment: Select `A2:A<whicheverrow>` >> go to conditional formatting >> new rule >> use a formula @MissComputing

Comment: Sorry you meant A2:A9 - got it, I think - verifying

Comment: You forgot to select the right range in column `A:A`. So start from row 2 and select all cells in that column downwards @MissComputing

Comment: Thank so much - worked - but there's no way to set the two colours? Red for the others?

Comment: @MissComputing, what do you mean with two colours and "red for the others"? Can't you just select your range and fill the background green? Conditional formatting will still color the "others" red.

Comment: This is hugely helpful @JvdV but the one problem I'm having is that the list of original members in my actual spreadsheet have commas seperating the first name and last name in the format: Lastname, Firstname. If you try your formula again with the commas, it does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can the existing formula please be adapted to include searching with the comma seperated values in column1

Comment: So you changed your sample data and the question alltogether? @MissComputing. Either way, it should be an easy fix. Can you edit your question so it's readable and understandable.

Comment: @MissComputing, just change your question and make it readable as of right now it's not. And in the future refrain from changing questions and data.

Comment: @MissComputing, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thankyou - I have a follow on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65825530/adapting-existing-excel-function-to-find-a-match-in-a-different-column-and-remov